# show data on webpage from database by checking first letter of sentence

Tags: javascript, php

I am fetching sentences from database to show on webpage by taking first letter of sentences stored, which is provided by user input.

I need to fetch stored data from my database 'search' and show it on a webpage. The database has 2 columns:

```
1 col- index (consists of a number)
2 col- answers (consists of some sentence)
```

NOW my problem is "How to fetch whole sentence by checking only first alphabet"

Example:  suppose col/answers/ consist of some 3 sentences

```
"is , did the chef is"
"nor, whether, that, the"
"hurting, to do"
.....so on.....
```

now I search for "n" on webpage and after submitting my form then database will send all the sentences stored with starting alphabet "n".
same process for all other letters.

And I can checking for up to 6 letters at the same time. (by different input field and all of them fetch data after submitting)

Like in

```
1 input: "f" letter---
2 input: "e" letter--
3 input: "j" letter--
4 input: "r" letter--
5 input: "q" letter--
6 input: "h" letter--
```

Now as I submit the form it will show all the sentences starting from "f,e,j,r,q,h" respectively.

Comment: What you are trying to do ?

Comment: Sorting results by alphabetical order ?

Comment: edited my post..see first line @bader

Comment: "fetch whole sentence by checking only first alphabet". The *first alphabet*? You mean the first letter? And your sentences are just groups of words, aren’t they?

Comment: yes..by checking only first letter from group of words or any sentence....@idmean

Comment: "is , did the chef is"   will show if search for "i"...
"nor, whether, that, the"  will show if search for "n"...
"hurting, to do" will show if search for "h"....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [LIKE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) clause of SQL to match pattern. Do it for all inputs separately or in a loop, whatever suits your code.